# Include data from another row in in the same table with sqlalchemy query

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table (SQLite) which contains rows of data in the following format:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    ID    |      start       |        end       |    type_id    |    user_id    |
+----------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+
|    1     | 2020-01-01 17:00 | 2020-01-02 05:00 |       1       |       10      |
|    2     | 2020-01-01 17:00 | 2020-01-02 05:00 |       1       |       9       |
|    3     | 2020-01-02 02:00 | 2020-01-02 03:00 |       2       |       10      |
```

I would like to write an sqlalchemy query (not Flask-sqlalchemy, though) that finds all data where the `type_id=1`, and then also find the those with `type_id=2` that occur at the same time as a `type_id=1` and return all the information for that row as well as the start of the matching `type_id=1`.

for example, say row 1 and 3 occurred at the same time and it's the same user I want to return the following:

```
[
  {"ID":1, "start":"2020-01-01 17:00", "end":"2020-01-02 05:00", "type_id":1, "user_id":10},
  {"ID":3, "start":"2020-01-02 02:00", "end":"2020-01-02 03:00", "type_id":2, "user_id":10, "date":"2020-01-01"}
]
```

I'm open to having an additional 'group' column and I can ensure that things that occur at the same time with the same user_id have the same group id when they're added, but still how to have a query to get all of this in one or two queries without a brute force for loop?

At the moment, the only way I can think to do it is to first query for all the `type_id=1` then query all the type ID=3 and then for each of those run a new query that returns the start date of the other matching row. Something like this:

```
type_1s=db.query(TABLE).filter(TABLE.start>=some_input_date, TABLE.end<=some_input_date, TABLE.type_id==1)
```

then

```
type_2s=db.query(TABLE).filter(TABLE.start>=some_input_date, TABLE.end<=some_input_date, TABLE.type_id==2)
for row in type_2s:
  #run a new query in here to find rows where the user_id matches the dates overlap and the type_id is 1.
```

I can then concatenate the two lists to ensure that those with type_id=2 are correctly grouped together with the appropriate type_id=1.

An even better solution, should anyone have a suggestion, would be just one query to produce the following dataset:

```
{
  "2020-01-01":[
    {10:[
          {"ID":1, "start":"2020-01-01 17:00", "end":"2020-01-02 05:00", "type_id":1, "user_id":10},
          {"ID":3, "start":"2020-01-02 02:00", "end":"2020-01-02 03:00", "type_id":2, "user_id":10}
        ],
     9:[
         {"ID":2, "start":"2020-01-01 17:00", "end":"2020-01-02 05:00", "type_id":1, "user_id":9,
       ],
    }
  ],
```

Comment: There may be a solution in using the alias option from sqlalchemy.orm. I could set an alias for the same table, then add a set of filters to get those of type_id=2 for the user and date requirements, and then a second filter to grab just the start component of type_id 1 that bounds the start and end time of the type_id 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to include an aliased version of the `TABLE` and then adding an additional filter which uses that as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

MATCH=aliased(TABLE)

db.query(
  TABLE,
  MATCH.start.label('date') # <-- this renames what would be the same column name
).filter(
  TABLE.start>=some_input_date,
  TABLE.end<=some_input_date,
  TABLE.type_id==2
).filter(
  MATCH.start<=TABLE.start,
  MATCH.end>=TABLE.end,
  MATCH.user_id==TABLE.user_id,
  MATCH.type_id==1
)
```

This gives a list of those of type_id 2 including the date they belong to.
While it still means there's a two-step solution (first get the type 1s, then the type 2s) it at least avoids a brute force approach to do many individual queries via a for loop.